# How to call a function in an .ascx file inside another .ascx from an .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one .aspx page(main) with one .ascx(pageA) on it which have another .ascx(pageB).

On pageA there is a Button function called "SaveButton", from the main page I can execute that function with: pageA.SaveButton(null, EventArgs.Empty);

My problem is: If the button instead is on pageB how do I execute the function then from the main page?

Comment: Why can't you put the save button on the ASPX?

Comment: No, I cant. It's a complex setup from an existing software I have to modify.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that main.aspx has two UserControls called pageA.ascx and pageB.ascx. Or are you saying that pageA.ascx contains UserControl pageB.ascx. In other words are both user controls on the page, or is pageB nested in pageA?

Comment: Webform main contains usercontrol pageA and pageA contains usercontrol pageB, so yes it is nested.

Comment: Ok then so you will not be able to call pageB.SaveButton() from the main.aspx, you will be able to call it from pageA.ascx. You could however add another function to pageA.ascx that then calls pageB.SaveButton()

Comment: The fact that this save button already exists on a user control suggests that other user controls might already be "subscribing" to the button's clicks.  In that case, you should be able to mimic what's being done in those controls.  Otherwise, where's no easy way to do what you want without code smells.  Your best bet is to refactor the code by moving the save button to the ASPX and then creating a .Save() method on each user control and then call them on the save.

Comment: It's not the same button on pageB, that's the problem. I have to first trigger button on pageA and then on pageB.

Comment: Wait a minute, I misunderstood your question.  If ControlB is nested inside ControlA (they're controls, not pages), just make a public .Save() method in ControlB.  You'll then be able to have ControlA's save method call ControlB.Save().

Comment: oscilatingcretin is right, one option is to make a public method and call them from the page. Another good option would be raise an Event when either pageA or pageB Save methods are called. You could consume the events on the main.aspx and centralize your Save function.

Comment: @Thomas is that SaveButton(null, EventArgs.Empty) an onclick event handler for pageA? and does pageB also have a save button with an event handler? Perhaps you could provide some code.